# Adding an arrow on both sides of a div using CSS?

Tags: css, css-shapes

I want an arrow on the left and right side of a div. Like here, but on both sides: http://cssarrowplease.com/

Is that possible?

Comment: Sure it is, so... what have you tried yourself???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an extra div inside `.arrow`, on which you add a `:before` and `:after` pseudo class as well. (Note: the extra div is necessary because of the extra border. The border is created by creating two overlapping divs, `:before` and `:after`)

```css
.arrow_box { 
    position: relative; 
    background: #88b7d5; 
    border: 4px solid #c2e1f5; 
    width: 200px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before { 
    bottom: 100%; 
    border: solid transparent; 
    content: " "; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
} 
.arrow_box:after { 
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0); 
    border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
} 
.arrow_box:before { 
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0); 
    border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5; 
    border-width: 36px; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -36px;
}
.arrow_box > div:after, .arrow_box > div:before { 
    top: 100%; 
    border: solid transparent; 
    content: ""; 
    height: 0; 
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
} 
.arrow_box > div:after { 
    border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0); 
    border-top-color: #88b7d5;
    border-width: 30px;
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -30px; 
} 
.arrow_box > div:before { 
    border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0); 
    border-top-color: #c2e1f5; 
    border-width: 36px; 
    left: 50%; 
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow_box">
    <div>
        bla!<br />
        bla!<br />
        bla!<br />
        bla!<br />
        bla!<br />
        bla!<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4Yf4B/).