# add an arrow infront and after a div

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I tried to add an arrow shape to a div. i managed to add it to the end of the div but i am struggling to figure out how to add it to the front as well without using a new class. Is it possible to achieve it with only one class?

[image: example]

edit: my answer to the question with a different shape approach,
i think they are all 3 very useful:

```css
.arrow {
  margin-left: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:100px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
}

.arrow:after {
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-width: 50px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.arrow:before {
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-color: pink;
  border-width: 50px;
  left: 400px;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow">
  1
</div>
<div class="arrow">
  2
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an arrow on both sides of a div using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722059/adding-an-arrow-on-both-sides-of-a-div-using-css)

Comment: @TylerH thanks haven't seen that one, its a bit different though but i guess the inner div will be necessary than..i will try to adapt it and answer if i succeed. If someone has a better way please shout out. thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified chevron shape, from this page: https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ (borrowed idea, credits to mr Anthony Ticknor:))

```css
.chevron {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 60px;
  width: 260px;
  line-height:60px;
 
 margin-bottom:10px;

}

.chevron:before {
   content: ''; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 0; 
   left: 3%; 
   height: 50%; 
   width: 100%;
  
    transform: skew(25deg, 0deg);
    border:1px solid red;
    border-bottom:none;
}

.chevron:after {
   content: ''; 
   position: absolute; 
   top: 50%; 
   left: 3%; 
   height: 50%; 
   width: 100%;
   
    transform: skew(-25deg, 0deg);
       border:1px solid red;
    border-top:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="chevron">1</div>
<div class="chevron">2</div>
```

So, one div, and two pseudo-elements, properly scewed, with borders hidden, where needed.

Comment: If you are adding text inside the shape, and coloring the chevron background, you will probably need to use `z-index: -1` for the `:before` and `:after` rules.

Answer (score 2):

You will need an inner element. What that element is, is purely up to you. Here I've used a `<span>` to make the left arrow appear.

```css
.arrow {
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid green;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: none;
}

.arrow:after,.arrow span:after  {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 128px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

.arrow:before,.arrow span:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 129px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid green;
  z-index: 1;
}
.arrow span:after {
  left: 0;
}

.arrow span:before {
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrow"><span></span>1</div>
<div class="arrow"><span></span>2</div>
<div class="arrow"><span></span>3</div>
<div class="arrow"><span></span>4</div>
<div class="arrow"><span></span>5</div>
```

Comment: ahh that makes sense, i managed to get something similar without the inner element but not sure if it makes sense :) http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/bBQpKa

Comment: That works fine, but you won't be able to have a separate background color for the inner content, and the border with that solution.